# How to cycle an integer between a minimum and maximum value with one line

Tags: c

I'm trying to cycle an integer between a minimum and maximum value inside of a range, e.g., 0-2, so that if I increment or decrement the value, it's always inside the range.
Anything over maximum should snap to minimum, and anything below minimum should snap to maximum.
The following code works fine for incrementing, but not for decrementing:

```
current=(current+1)%(maximum+1);
```

Is there a similar trick that would work for decrementing, too?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking as your current code does the increment and wrap all together. If you are looking to force a value (that may have been changed somewhere above in the code) inside some range, a double ternary operator can do this.

Comment: Let `inc = 1` or `-1`.  `current=(current+inc +maximum+1)%(maximum+1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decrementing is equivalent to adding `maximum` when working mod `maximum + 1`, so as long as a negative `current` can’t come from anywhere else, `maximum` remains fixed, and `current + maximum` can’t overflow the integer type, you can make use of that:

```
current = (current + maximum) % (maximum + 1);
```

The operation being the same with just a choice of `1` or `maximum` is elegant in a way, but keep in mind that the branching version might be both more readable and faster:

```
/* increment */
current = current == maximum ? 0 : current + 1;

/* decrement */
current = current == 0 ? maximum : current - 1;
```